# how can i get the shape of my view in android

Tags: android

i've stumbled upon a  sample for using fragments.Whenever a tab is changed a fragment would rotate.using this:

`ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(leftFrag1.getView(), "rotationY",0,180).start`

The thing is that in the sample the fragment has only a background so it looks ok.My fragment has a few views on it and i don't want them to be rotated cause it looks bad.Is there a way to get only the view's rectangle to rotate or erase the layout that the view is related so that it look like the sample?
Thank you for your time